How to make player stick to collider in Unity
I'm trying to make a gameplay where you can jump between asteroids in a 0 gravity space. I want my player to stick to the asteroid and be able to walk along its surface until he jump to go away.
I was able to create something where I check surface and if the feet are grounded, I apply a force from the player toward the surface, but on sharp edges or if i go too fast, my check may fail and my player is propulsed away.
I need to be scratched until I decided not to.
My current code:
private void CheckGrounded()
{
    // Perform a raycast to check for ground, ignoring trigger colliders
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(feetPosition.position, -transform.up, feetDistanceCheck, groundLayer);

    if (hit)
    {
        // Align the player's rotation with the surface normal
        surfaceNormal = hit.normal;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(surfaceNormal.y, surfaceNormal.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle), 0.1f);
        rb.freezeRotation = true;
        isGrounded = true;

        // Apply surface attachment if not jumping
        if (jumpTimer <= 0)
            ApplySurfaceAttachment();
    }
    else
    {
        isGrounded = false;
        rb.freezeRotation = false;
    }
}
private void ApplySurfaceAttachment()
{
    Vector2 force = surfaceNormal * -surfaceTension;
    rb.AddForce(force);
}

The actual good behavior to keep: you can choose to go slowly to a place, stop, jump straight. Or speedrun by walking fast and jump to keep the momentum while unscratching the surface.

You could keep a reference to the last asteroid you grounded on -> current main attraction and always apply a gravity force towards this one

To get the behavior you want, you should add a force of gravity towards the center of the asteroid when the player gets within a certain distance and have a high jump speed so that the player is able to get far enough from the asteroid. This will cause the player to be still attracted to the asteroid even if they lose contact unless they get far enough away. The force's magnitude and maximum distance can be tuned so that the player only leaves the asteroid if the player jumps.
